# I have a form validator and I have to click twice the send button to send data to ajax - why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

So the test scenario is simple:

1) run my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/1364/

2) in e.g. third textfield add some value to the existing one

3) hit `save` button

4) the field turns green, but there's no popup.

5) hit `save` button again and then the popup appears.

Why is it working like this?

Basically I want to validate the fields and send data to ajax later on. Since I don't know how to emulate the sending to ajax on jsfiddle, I left the simple popup there - you can still see the weird behavior though. I think the error is because I'm using those two properties together:

```
success: function (element) {
            element.addClass('valid')
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');

        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { alert("here!");
        }
```

But on the other hand I'm not sure if it's the cause... What can be the problem here?

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging.  The jQuery Form Validator is a totally different plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky for that clue, I'll keep it in mind! And also - of course - thanks for providing the correct solution for my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the `success` callback function.  Anything you do with `highlight` would get "undone" using [`unhighlight`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight).

[The `success` callback option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) was designed to use the error label element when the field passes validation.  In other words, the error label is normally not needed when the field passes validation, so you would use the `success` option if you wanted to display a "success" message in place of the error message when validation passes.

Anyway, use `unhighlight` with `highlight` and it will work fine.  You also incorrectly spelled your `has-success` class.

```
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/azxpckg5/**